# I am a secondary school student and I think I have proven an open result, how do I get it out?

Tags: research-process, publications, mathematics

I am pretty firmly convinced that I have proven the non-existence of odd perfect numbers and now I am wanting to write it up (Qi: What is the best way or writing maths on a computers?). I also desire to know the general standards of publishing small results such as this so being pointed in the direction of any of the literature to give me idea what I need to write up would be much appreciated. Finally, I need to know where I can submit the result for review and (hopefully) publication. thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do you know when your independent findings are paper-worthy?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13818/how-do-you-know-when-your-independent-findings-are-paper-worthy/)

Comment: That's not a "small" result.  If you know how to formulate the proof, you know how to write it up.  Submit it to a number theory journal.

However, as I'm sure you know, there's a good chance that you're mistaken.  It would be wise to show your proof to a mathematician first.

Comment: _What is the best way or writing maths on a computer?_ — LaTeX.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading Henry Cohn's advice (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cohn/Thoughts/advice.html).

Comment: @Moriarty  I don't think this question is very similar to that one.  A proof of the existence of odd perfect numbers would _definitely_ be worth publishing, because it would solve a well-known open problem.

Comment: That being said, my advice is to worry some more about the correctness of your argument before worrying about the details of typing a paper.  I'm not just saying this because you're a secondary school student.  Any mathematician who thinks he or she has discovered a solution to a long-standing open problem should be _very_ skeptical and enlist the help of other mathematicians in going over the argument carefully to make sure that it is correct.  Many mistakes are discovered at this stage.

Comment: If I were you, I would assume that the proof was wrong but in a way you don't understand, and try to pick holes all over it. This is what a referee for such a result would do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as I always say, the academia is a circle with its own established convention to follow. In terms of paper publication, you have to learn how to describe things using the terminology and way of expression accepted by the academia. Normally you need several years of regular university education to master these.

But in your particular case, I think it would be easier if you could find a mentor in the university (e.g. a professor or a research) who really understands and recognize your research result and has your trust. He could teach you what is a logic and sound research and how to speak in the language used in the academic community.

Another solution is just publish your result on your personal blog (I mean a well-known blog system like google+ or wordpress, so that the timestamp of your post will tell the world you're the original holder of the idea) and try to make your result get noticed by the academic people.

If you really want to challenge people's stereotype about academic paper author, you could also try to publish paper yourself. But it is definitely extremely hard.

Comment: I mean publish on a well-known public blog system, like google+ or wordpress. The timestamp of the article will tell the world who's the original holder of the idea.

Comment: @Jhz832 I have not personally used arXiv, but I believe the "timestamp idea" is one feature of that site...

Comment: @Alexandros but thanks for your reminding, i've updated ;)

Comment: Publishing on ArXiv for the first time requires an "endorsment" from an established author. The OP will likely not have that.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni  But if his result is correct, he'll have absolutely no trouble finding an endorsement, provided he's willing to show it to an established mathematician.

Comment: google+ is not a blog system. And it is absolutely unsuitable for mathematics.